# How can I continue execution after a Dial from Asterisk

Tags: linux, asterisk, dial

I want to continue execution after a dial (dial(SIP/name)) from the server Asterisk
with, for example, a function playtones.
How can I do that ?
I did it with between two softphones but with directly Asterisk
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may use option 'g' of the Dial application to continue in next priority after called party hangs up.

You may also check options H and h for allowing hanging up.

https://www.voip-info.org/asterisk-cmd-dial/